# Can't register component locally in Vue.js. "[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Have a problem with registering component locally in Vue.js app.
I'm trying to use MovieCard.vue inside it's parent MainView.vue.
Made everythig as in the Vue docs, but still getting this error:

```
 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <movie-card> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <MainView> at src\components\MainView.vue
       <VApp>
         <App> at src\App.vue
           <Root>
```

Here goes the code for **MovieCard.vue**(child component)

```
<template>
<div>
 <!-- <v-card class="movie-card" height="30vh" hover>
        <v-card-media :src="'http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + movie-info.poster_path" height="100%">
         <v-card class="movie-card__info-cover" width="100%" height="100%">
             {{this.movie-info}}
         </v-card>
        </v-card-media>
       </v-card> -->
</div>      
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "MovieCard",
    props: ["movie-info"],
    data() { 
        return {
        visible: false
        }
    },
    created() {
        console.log("Info:", this["movie-info"])
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

And for **MainView.vue**(parent component):

```
<template>
  <v-container class="main-view" column>
    <v-btn color="pink" dark small absolute bottom left fab></v-btn>
    <v-tabs centered grow color="pink" slot="extension" slider-color="yellow">
      <v-tab class="main-view__option" @click="setCategory('popular')">
        Popular
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab class="main-view__option" @click="setCategory('upcoming')">
        Upcoming
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab class="main-view__option" @click="setCategory('topRated')">
        Top Rated
      </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
    <v-container class="movie-cards__container" fluid grid-list-xl>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex xs3 md2 class="" v-for="n in this.movies.movieLists.list" :key="n.id">
          <movie-card :movie-info="n"></movie-card>
        </v-flex>
        <infinite-loading @infinite="infiniteHandler" spinner="spiral"></infinite-loading>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-container>
</template>


<script>
import { mapState, mapActions, mapMutations } from 'vuex';
import InfiniteLoading from 'vue-infinite-loading';
import MovieCard from "./MovieCard"
console.log(MovieCard)
export default {
  name: 'MainView',
  components: {MovieCard}, 
  data () {
    return {
      chosenCategory: 'popular'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState([
      'movies'
    ])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      "getNextPageByCategory",
      'setCategory'
    ]),
    async infiniteHandler($state) {
      await this.getNextPageByCategory(this.chosenCategory);
      $state.loaded();
      console.log("yay");
    },
    ...mapMutations([])
  },
  components: {
    InfiniteLoading
  }
}
</script>
```

Also, I've noticed the fact that if i put the same component into my App.vue root component, it works as intended(like any other subcomponents, which are registered locally inside App.vue(for example MainView.vue)).

In addition, I'll say that i'm using Vuex and Vuetify inside my app.

Tried to solve this issue for hours, but for now no results...

**Thank you in advance for your help!**

Comment: in MainView.vue(parent component) you have two components objects.That is you issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to define your component in `MainView` like this :

```
components: {
  'movie-card': MovieCard
}
```

edit: maybe it's because you define your components twice

Comment: Tried it already. No results. Also tried to change name inside MovieCard.vue to "movie-card".

Comment: @sovalina is right, you define components twice in MainView, try to do it only once, like: components: { 'movie-card': MovieCard, 'infinite-loading': InfiniteLoading }

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!!! You saved hours of my life :) Silly mistake, but for now one more thing to be aware of when creating objects in js, haha

Answer (score 1):

In the OP question, he made the mistake defining `components` twice in `MainView.vue`, so that the latter `components` overrode the first one, which is the one declared `movie-card` component, so only

```
components: {
  InfiniteLoading
}
```

is the valid registered component at the end of the day,

```
components: {MovieCard},
```

was overridden

---

And today, I've gone through the same shit

```
Unknown custom element: <movie-card> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

And the mistake of mine was I **mistyped the word `components` to `component`** without the `s`. So if any of you guys go later and about to see this kind of error, chances you've **mistyped** something.

The Vue error prompt was also smart enough to ask us `did you register the component correctly?`, yet we made the assumption that we did, but hold on, we likely didn't.

That being said, the problem had nothing to do with

```
components: {
  'movie-card': MovieCard 
}
// the above is the same at the below in Vue
components: {
  MovieCard
}
```

If you read [Sovalina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50079179/9787887), please notice that the answer is his **edit**

---

Another thing btw, I've thought the problem **had something to do with `recursive components`**, so I `made sure providing the "name" option`, but as you could read [this](https://dev.to/proticm/vue-and-recursive-components-15n7), it didn't have a thing to do with `"name" option` cause `movie-card` was not a recursive component. In my case, I resolved my problem by adding a character `s`, not any `name`.

Comment: Thanks, same thing to me, i was declaring compontents instead components